# Correct decorators for C# serializer

Tags: c#, serialization

I have an xml string which has  the following structure :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://someurl">
   xmlns:v5="http://someotherurl"
   xmlns:v51="http://evensomeotherurl">

  <soapenv:Header>
      <v5:Client> APP </v5:Client>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <v51:SomeAction>
       <v51:Value>1<v/51:Value>
    </v51:SomeAction>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

If I use this site https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/, I get this class conversion:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace Xml2CSharp
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName="Header", Namespace="http://someurl")]
    public class Header {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Client", Namespace="http://someotherurl")]
        public string Client { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="SomeAction", Namespace="http://evensomeotherurl")]
    public class SomeAction {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Value", Namespace="http://evensomeotherurl")]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="Body", Namespace="http://someurl")]
    public class Body {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="SomeAction", Namespace="http://evensomeotherurl")]
        public SomeAction SomeAction { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="Envelope", Namespace="http://someurl")]
    public class Envelope 
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Header", Namespace="http://someurl")]
        public Header Header { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Body", Namespace="http://someurl")]
        public Body Body { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="soapenv", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Soapenv { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="v5", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string V5 { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="v51", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string V51 { get; set; }
    }

}
```

The problem is, this class does not serialize to the original string anymore. How can I correct the decorators so once I serialize an instance of this object I get the string exactly as it is before deserialization.

#### Edit

This is the way I am serializing :

```
public string ToXml<T>(T obj) 
{
    using(var stringwriter = new System.IO.StringWriter()) 
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
        serializer.Serialize(stringwriter, obj);
        return HttpUtility.HTMLDecode(stringwriter.ToString())
    } 
}
```

Comment: decorators? You mean the `[attributes]`? Apart from this, what do you mean by "does not serialize to the original anymore"? What do you get instead?

Comment: I´m pretty sure you don´t need `SoapEnv` and `V5` and `V51` in your `Envelope`-class

Comment: @HimBromBeere Yes, I do not. But the service I am dealing with is a piece of s..., so I have no other option that to comply. If I serialize that class and send it as it is, the request fails.

Comment: @HimBromBeere by "does not serialize to the original anymore" means that if if you create an instance of that class and serialize it, you will never get the string I initially used to create the object from. For instance, Envelope is missing the "soapenv:" attribute, as well as all the inner fields are missing the "v5:" and "v51:" attributes

Comment: Which one serializer do you use for (de)serialization? There are many of them.

Comment: Does the service that you take this xml from provide a wsdl or asmx description?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov The problem is, I cant reference the service with a wsdl directly, (which would be ideal ) since I am actually hitting a wrapper on top of it. Long story short, my company is luckily moving away from this ugly pattern to a JSON RESTful pattern. But some dinosaurs, like this one, are still needed so I need to create a wrapper too. So basically, my service is wrapper on top of a wrapper. I can directly  hit the old dinosaur.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Ill share how I am serializing, one minute